# How to import large database and track its progress in windows os

Tags: mysql, database, windows, wamp

I have really large database to upload. its 5gb in size. I know command line way to import such large files as-

```
mysql -u {uname} -p {password} {dbname} < {file name.sql}
```

It works but since database is so large I am not sure when it will finish uploading. I have tried refreshing phpmyadmin but it always remains then same like nothing happing.

So if anyone can tell me a way to track its progress on windows os i would really appreciate that help.

**Note:**
The command is working , it creates 5 tables and did 175 entries but after that there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing your MySQL database from some other client (another instance of `mysql`, for example).

Ask for row counts in your large tables.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bigtable
```

These row counts should increase steadily as your database loads.

If you're loading multi-million-row InnoDB tables, you probably need to be concerned about how often you `COMMIT` your newly loaded rows to the database. If you `COMMIT` every single row (that is, if you autocommit), see you next week. But that's another question.